# Get marker id in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I want to pass related marker id by clicking marker on google map. I am using marker.getId() function to retrieve marker id. But the marker id is not passing along with url. How can i do this? Any Help?

```
function AddressMap(lat,lang,markerid)
{   
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'map': map,
    position: latLng,
    'latitude' :lat,
    'longitude' :lang,
    icon: image,
    shadow: shadow,
    id: markerid

});

markers.push(marker);   
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {               
          window.location = "www.cickstart.com/" + marker.getId();

        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try directly to access the id:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {               
  window.location = "www.cickstart.com/" + marker.id;
});
```

Answer (score 10):

the best way to do this is add a metadata to marker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.metadata = {type: "point", id: 1};
```

if you have so many marker push the marker to array marker. 
You can add any data that you want. and simply call it, set it or get it.

the sample like this one:

```
markers[0].metadata.id
```