# marker metadata?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have more of an approach question, than a code question.

Let's say I have 2 webpages (page a & page b) on the same domain.

User is on page a. They click a link. I'd like to take the user to page b, and open an info window.

My thought was to add some sort of id, or data attribute to a marker, and then, when the user gets to page B, an event fires opening the correct point/infowindow.

I read something about marker metadata:   marker.metadata = {type: "point", id: 1};

But I am confused at to what this actually does. In the resulting html/map, is the marker an element with this id?

Thanks in advance for any shedding of the light!

Comment: You can add metadata to markers:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13097054

Answer (score 0):

General questions are always harder to answer, because as you narrow down the scope you will need to revise your decision anyway.

One thing that is clear is that it is not a good idea to fiddle with the marker object directly.

The infoWindow does not have a property you can set to make it visible, you just call open() and close(), so as trivial as this might be, I would just consider using an array or a HashMap of infowindows and then read the URL param to decide which element of the Array will we call the open() function on.

If you want to store additional information in a Marker I would consider extending the Marker
class: IdedMarker.prototype = new google.maps.Marker(); 
and then add a property on it and methods to getId and setId.

HTH