# Google Maps - Pass map id and marker longlat to a hidden input element

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**Goal**: I have several maps on a same template. Everytime a map is clicked, I would like to add markers and pass their longlat and corresponding map id to hidden input elements.

**Problem**: Map id passed to input name onclick is `undefined` like below (it's supposed to be something like 'map'+int).

```
<input value="(35.69906406361917, 139.81689870357513)" name="undefined" type="hidden">
```

I checked [Get marker id in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397877/get-marker-id-in-google-maps) but the onclick functions is slightly different.

**Code**:

```
var maps = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var myOptions = {
        #settings
    };

    maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), myOptions);

    var currentMap = maps[i];

    (function(currentMap) {
        currentMap.addListener('click', function(e) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.latLng,
                map: currentMap
            });

            var data = document.createElement('input');
            data.name = currentMap.id;
            data.type = 'hidden';
            data.value = e.latLng;
            document.forms[0].appendChild(data);
        });
    })(currentMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking your code and analyzing what you are trying to achieve, I found out that there's a better way to implement it. Instead of creating a new hidden input on every click, let's just store the coordinates and mapId in an array. Btw, the reason you are having this **undefined** is because the **id** you are referencing is a non-existing property.

For example, you have 3 maps on your page, the ids are: map1, map2, and map3.

In your existing implementation, `var map = [];` is already an array. This is correct. We just need to add 2 more arrays: the marker array and the coords array.

```
var marker = [];
var coords = [];
```

Now, let's first create a function currentMap() that accepts two arguments: **mapObject** and **mapId**. These two arguments are essential for adding an event and for storing mapIds into our **coords array**. The first argument, **mapObject**, is the one will be using the **.addListener** method. The idea is to add a marker, on every map click and store the acquired coordinates to the **array of objects** together with the mapId that is being supplied by the second argument. The array object properties: **mapId, lat**, and **lng**.

The currentMap() function and definition:

```
  function currentMap(mapObject, mapId) {
    mapObject.addListener('click', function(e){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: e.latLng,
            map: mapObject
        });    
      coords.push({
        mapId: mapId,
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
      });
      //console.log(coords);
    });
  }
```

The **array object**:

```
{
 lat:-27.059125784374057
 lng:122.080078125
 mapId:"map1"
}
```

On the other hand, the initMap() function, we can use the `for loop` that you already created. Everything seems fine in your current initMap() implementation, we just simply remove unnecessary lines which we will no longer needed. And also, inside the loop, call the currentMap() function we recently created and then supply the necessary arguments.

```
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
      map[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng
      }); 
      currentMap(map[i], 'map'+i);
    } 
  }
```

Whole code below:

```js
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map = [];
      var marker = [];
      var coords = [];
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
          map[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng
          }); 
          currentMap(map[i], 'map'+i);
        } 
      }
      function currentMap(mapObject, mapId) {
        mapObject.addListener('click', function(e){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.latLng,
                map: mapObject
            });    
          coords.push({
            mapId: mapId,
            lat: e.latLng.lat(),
            lng: e.latLng.lng()
          });
          //console.log(coords);
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      .map {
        height: 200px;
        padding:10px 0;
        display:block;
        margin:10px 0;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="map1" class="map"></div>
    <div id="map2" class="map"></div>
    <div id="map3" class="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

And that's it! Your coordinates + mapId are stored in **coords** array.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining the logic step by step! My code is running properly now. Just 1 question. Are there any pros of using arrays instead of hidden inputs?

Comment: In my own experience, arrays plays an important role in development. You can check [JS Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) to learn more. Everything in programming has their pros and cons, it really depends on how you would use them. There are certain situations in which hidden inputs plays a vital role.